# List messages ordered by conversations for all users

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

My use case is an admin view to see all the messages in the db.

I would like a list of message ordered by conversations and beginning dates, the idea is to be able to see each message in its context.

A conversation is a list of interactions between two users.

I don't have a `conversation` table, only a `message` table.

From this data sample :

```
id   sender      recipient
--------------------------
1    marc        rémi
2    gépéto      sylvain
3    rémi        marc
4    julie       georgette
5    rémi        marc
6    denis       julie
7    julie       rémi
8    sylvain     gépéto
9    denis       marc
10   denis       julie
```

I would like to obtain :

```
id   sender      recipient
--------------------------
1    marc        rémi
3    rémi        marc
5    rémi        marc
2    gépéto      sylvain
8    sylvain     gépéto
4    julie       georgette
6    denis       julie
10   denis       julie
7    julie       rémi
9    denis       marc
```

For now, I was more simply looking to get the first messages of each conversations as a first step towards the wanted result :

```
SELECT message.id, message.sender , message.recipient
FROM message
GROUP BY message.sender, message.recipient
HAVING message.id = min(message.id)
ORDER BY message.id DESC;
```

But I can't get this right, I get two conversations instead of one for all bidirectionals conversations :

```
id   sender      recipient
--------------------------
8    sylvain     gépéto
2    gépéto      sylvain
```

So, I'm stuck here ... And I would appreciate some tips !

Almost forgot: [SQL Fiddle with the sample and the last query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc66b/1)

Comment: Because sender A and recipient B is not the same as sender B and recipient A, as far as SQL is concerned, so this query will give you the minimum id for all conversations where sender is A and recipient is B.  BTW, since message.id is not in the group by, it should have an aggregate function applied to it.  MySQL is "nice" in that it does not enforce this, and indeterminately gives you one of the message.ids from the group.  This query would fail in Oracle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following query to get the `id` of the first message of each conversation:

```
SELECT MIN(id),
       IF(sender > recipient, sender, recipient) AS participantA, 
       IF(sender > recipient, recipient, sender) AS participantB
FROM message 
GROUP BY participantA, participantB
```

Now use the above query in a derived table to get desired result:

```
SELECT id, sender, recipient
FROM (
  SELECT id, sender, recipient,
         IF(sender > recipient, sender, recipient) AS participantA, 
         IF(sender > recipient, recipient, sender) AS participantB
  FROM message) AS t1
INNER JOIN (  
  SELECT MIN(id) AS minId,
         IF(sender > recipient, sender, recipient) AS participantA, 
         IF(sender > recipient, recipient, sender) AS participantB
  FROM message 
  GROUP BY participantA, participantB
) AS t2 ON t1.participantA = t2.participantA AND t1.participantB = t2.participantB
ORDER BY t2.minId
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc66b/22)

Answer (score 2):

**[SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc66b/35)**

```
SELECT m.*, CASE 
                WHEN sender <= recipient THEN concat(sender,'-',recipient)
                ELSE concat(recipient,'-', sender)
            END as conversation
FROM message m
ORDER BY conversation, id
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| id |  sender | recipient |    conversation |
|----|---------|-----------|-----------------|
|  6 |   denis |     julie |     denis-julie |
| 10 |   denis |     julie |     denis-julie |
|  9 |   denis |      marc |      denis-marc |
|  4 |   julie | georgette | georgette-julie |
|  2 |  gépéto |   sylvain |  gépéto-sylvain |
|  8 | sylvain |    gépéto |  gépéto-sylvain |
|  7 |   julie |      rémi |      julie-rémi |
|  1 |    marc |      rémi |       marc-rémi |
|  3 |    rémi |      marc |       marc-rémi |
|  5 |    rémi |      marc |       marc-rémi |
```

This is first aproach, if you need `marc-rémi` be first you need include another select to get `MIN()` for each conversation.

Exact solution **[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc66b/37)**

```
SELECT conversation_id, T.id, T.sender, T.recipient, T.conversation
FROM (
    SELECT CASE 
               WHEN sender <= recipient THEN concat(sender,'-',recipient)
               ELSE concat(recipient,'-', sender)
           END as conversation,
           MIN(id) as conversation_id
    FROM message m
    GROUP BY conversation    
    ) as convesation_start
JOIN (
    SELECT m.*, CASE 
                    WHEN sender <= recipient THEN concat(sender,'-',recipient)
                    ELSE concat(recipient,'-', sender)
                END as conversation
    FROM message m
    ) as T
  ON 
  convesation_start.conversation = T.conversation
ORDER BY conversation_id, T.id
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| conversation_id | id |  sender | recipient |    conversation |
|-----------------|----|---------|-----------|-----------------|
|               1 |  1 |    marc |      rémi |       marc-rémi |
|               1 |  3 |    rémi |      marc |       marc-rémi |
|               1 |  5 |    rémi |      marc |       marc-rémi |
|               2 |  2 |  gépéto |   sylvain |  gépéto-sylvain |
|               2 |  8 | sylvain |    gépéto |  gépéto-sylvain |
|               4 |  4 |   julie | georgette | georgette-julie |
|               6 |  6 |   denis |     julie |     denis-julie |
|               6 | 10 |   denis |     julie |     denis-julie |
|               7 |  7 |   julie |      rémi |      julie-rémi |
|               9 |  9 |   denis |      marc |      denis-marc |
```

Comment: This query will not list the conversations in the order defined in the OP.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I know I was following this instruction `For now, I was more simply looking to get the first messages of each conversations as a first step `

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Now I also include the exact solution

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this one:

```
SELECT id, sender, recipient
FROM (SELECT message.id, message.sender , message.recipient
            ,concat(greatest(message.sender,message.recipient)
                   ,least(message.sender,message.recipient)
                   ) as conv
       FROM message) as tab1
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT min(id) as min
           ,concat(greatest(message.sender,message.recipient)
                  ,least(message.sender,message.recipient)
                  ) as conv
      FROM message 
    GROUP BY conv) as tab2
ON tab1.conv = tab2.conv
ORDER BY tab2.min
```

- where conv is the identifier of each couple

here's the demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc66b/41

Comment: Just so you know, your solution is a little faster to execute than the solution of @GiorgosBetsos (but he answered first). Thanks for your help ! :)